# How to make stylus url() png to base64

Tags: css, url, base64, stylus

I`ve got installed stylus on my project, and I want to generate base64  from my png icons. I found this in documentation:

http://stylus-lang.com/docs/functions.url.html

but i dont get how it works

In my second project i'm using webpack, and after using embedurl('something', 'utf-8') it works great. How to make it work on clear stylus without webpacks etc?

Answer (score -1):

`embedurl` IS clear Stylus, see http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#embedurlpath-encoding